# Multiple windows in a single project

Tags: qt, qml, qwidget, qtquick2, qquickview

I have a requirement for my project to display two QML `Window`s each on one of the screen (one sender, one receiver). Both of the `.qml` requires me to include some Cpp models inside hence, I'm using `QQmlApplicationEngine` to register the Cpp models.

I found out that using `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` I'm able to display multiple `Window`s for a single project. This works perfectly fine for the first QML file. The code snippets looks like this:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine* engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine(Qurl("main.qml"));
QmlContext* context = engine.getContextProperty();

//do some Cpp models registering...

QQuickview *view = new QQuickview(engine,0);
QWidget* container = widget::createWindowContainer(view);  
//I realized I dont need to do container->show(); for the main.qml to appear..

//use desktop widget to move the 2nd container to the 2nd screen...
```

I decided to create a 2nd application engine for my `receive.qml` with a similar method. I soon realized that the `receive.qml` would never open even with `container2->show()`. Now, it is showing an empty page.

My questions are:

1. Is my approach correct or is there a better solution for this?
2. What signal do I need look out for to catch the window close
   event? I cant seem to be able to detect the signal when one of the
   window is closed. as I wanted to close the both when one has been
   detected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That can be done easier, for example:

**main.qml**

```js
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {

    Window {
        objectName: "wnd1"
        visible: true
    }

    Window {
        objectName: "wnd2"
        visible: true
    }
}
```

And so you can access these windows from C++ code:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QQuickWindow *wnd1 = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickWindow *>("wnd1");
    if(wnd1)
        wnd1->setTitle("Server");
    QQuickWindow *wnd2 = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickWindow *>("wnd2");
    if(wnd2)
        wnd2->setTitle("Client");
```

To catch a closing event you should use [QQuickWindow::closing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#closing) event

Comment: nice ! the solution works like a charm. it seems like we can only have 1 engine at anytime..

As for shifting the 2nd window to 2nd screen, 

I obtained the availableGeometry from qApplication::desktop and set the window2's x(), y() using wnd2->setX(..) & wnd2->setY(..) to get the desired position. Is it ok to set x, y directly via the QQuickWindow ? Or do I have to use QObject::setProperty ?

Comment: Update: from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

it seems that it is recommended to use setProperty to set the X and Y. I shall adopt this method.

Comment: You can use [Screen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html) item to adjust size and position in QML

Comment: It's not working for me. I put a Window in an Item and the Window never shows up.

Comment: It's not working for me too in Windows. Nothing shows up.

Comment: The answer is not about showing a `Window` but accessing multiple `Window` instances from c++. So the code is just for illustrating the solution, for example windows have no size etc., you have to adopt it to your code.

Comment: This seems to be broken on the latest Qt5 version on windows. The windows won't show at all. My workaround was to place the second window inside a Loader so it's not associated with the root window.

Comment: It works on windows for me on Qt 5.12 if i replace Item with QtObject.
See example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtquick-window-window-qml.html

Comment: How to do it in Qt 6.2, please?