# Multiple Screens with Qt

Tags: linux, qt

I want to have a single Qt application showing two windows on different display outputs(screens) on my Ubuntu 14.04 computer. Does someone know how to do that?

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html) of Qt for embedded linux is what I could find so far but it did not help me really.

**Edit:**
Based on your comments, I've done this but it doesn't work as it should:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQuickView view1(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Screen1.qml")));
  qDebug() << app.screens().length();

  QScreen* screen1 = app.screens().at(0);
  QScreen* screen2 = app.screens().at(1);

  view1.setGeometry(0,0,200,200);
  view1.setScreen(screen1);
  view1.show();

  QQuickView view2(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Screen2.qml")));
  view2.setGeometry(0,0,200,200);
  view2.setScreen(screen2);
  view2.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

The debug output is: `2`

This code is putting both views to the same display output, although the `qDebug` output gives the correct number of display outputs with correct names.

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, why are you reading the embedded linux documentation?  :-/  In the regular Qt5 docs you'll find [QScreen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) and [QWindow::setScreen()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#setScreen)... which I've not used but may suit your purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is **wrong geometry**. In these 2 lines of code, you place both windows on same position:

```
view1.setGeometry(0,0,200,200);
view2.setGeometry(0,0,200,200);
```

Instead of this, you can set the position (not sure if you need size also):

```
view1.setGeometry(screen1->geometry().x(),screen1->geometry().y(),200,200);
view2.setGeometry(screen2->geometry().x(),screen2->geometry().y(),200,200);
```

To change the position instead of changing both the position and the size, you can use the function `move`.

P.S. There may be some small typos as I wrote this code by memory, but the main idea should be clear for you.

Comment: move function of which class?

Comment: @OnurA `move` function of QQuickView in your case. Like `view1.move(screen1->geometry().x(),screen1->geometry().y());`

Comment: it doesn't have any move function? Can you find it from the Qt 5 documentation?

Comment: @OnurA, you are right. Mixed up with the QtWidget classes.

Comment: @OnurA, what a output. seems stackoverflow cut it.

Comment: no I deleted it because the reason was a small bug in my code. It worked as you suggested with the setGeometry method.

Comment: it is still interesting that setScreen didn't work and setGeometry is enough without the setScreen method. Now I just have setGeometry() and show() and that's it

Comment: @OnurA, you will need `setScreen` in case if you will call `showFullScreen`. Probably it is important in some other situations, but that is only one i faced.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113311/in-qt-5-whats-the-right-way-to-show-multi-monitor-full-screen-qwidget-windows) and [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203838/5653461). Also, refer to the documentation of [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html). Hope that helps !

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298810/multiple-windows-in-a-single-project) relevant?